# ZeroMQ Subscribers not receiving message from Publisher over an inproc: transport class

Tags: zeromq, publish-subscribe, distributed-computing, pyzmq, low-latency

I am fairly new to **`pyzmq`**. I am trying to understand **`inproc:`** transport class and have created this sample example to play with.

It looks a **`Publisher`** instance is publishing messages but **`Subscriber`** instances are **not** receiving any.

In case I move `Subscriber` instances into a separate **`process`** and change `inproc:` to a **`tcp:`** transport class, the example works.

Here is the code:

```
import threading
import time

import zmq

context = zmq.Context.instance()

address = 'inproc://test' 


class Publisher(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        self.socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)

        self.socket.bind(address)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            message = 'snapshot,current_time_%s' % str(time.time())
            print 'sending message %s' % message
            self.socket.send(message)
            time.sleep(1)


class Subscriber(object):
    def __init__(self, sub_name):
        self.name = sub_name
        self.socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
        self.socket.connect(address)

    def listen(self):
        while True:
            try:
                msg = self.socket.recv()
                a, b = msg.split(' ', 1)
                print 'Received message -> %s-%s-%s' % (self.name, a, b)
            except zmq.ZMQError as e:
                logger.exception(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread_a = []
    for i in range(0, 1):
        subs = Subscriber('subscriber_%s' % str(i))
        th = threading.Thread(target=subs.listen)
        thread_a.append(th)
        th.start()

    pub = Publisher()
    pub_th = threading.Thread(target=pub.run)

    pub_th.start()
```

Comment: `except ... pass` ... seriously? BTW: Upgrade to Python 3!

Comment: ;-), that was just a sample code. Fixed it in the example :).

Comment: So I ran into this on ZMQ 4.3.2 in C++. And ensured that bind was called before connect. And my receive call never receives anything. One thing I noticed in the bind and connect code documentation it claims these are async functions, making this even more problematic since just ensuring bind is called before connect may not be enough depending on how things are implemented. So I even ensured the bind was completed but even with that my receive still never returned with any data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### There is nothing wrong, but

ZeroMQ is a wonderfull toolbox.
It is full of smart, bright and self-adapting services under the hood, that literally save our poor lives in many ways.
Still it is worth to read and obey a few rules from the documentation.

**`inproc`** transport class has one such. **`.bind()`** first, before **`.connect()`**-s

> <sup>[ Page 38, Code Connected, Volume I ]</sup>
> ... **`inproc`** is an inter-thread signalling transport ... it is faster than **`tcp`** or **`ipc`**. **This transport has a specific limitation** compared to `tpc` and `icp`: the server **must** issue a **`bind` before** any client issues a **`connect`**. This is something future versions of ØMQ ***may*** fix, but at present this defines how you use `inproc` sockets.

So, as an example:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    pub    = Publisher()
    pub_th = threading.Thread( target = pub.run )
    pub_th.start()
    # give it a place to start before .connect()-s may take place
    # give it a time  to start before .connect()-s may take place
    sleep(0.5)

    thread_a = []
    for i in range( 0, 1 ):
        subs = Subscriber( 'subscriber_%s' % str( i ) )
        th   = threading.Thread( target = subs.listen )
        thread_a.append( th )
        th.start()
```